# Is there a simple model for calculating the gain of a Quantum Cascade Laser?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser

Does a simple model of a Quantum Cascade Laser that can lead to a formula of its gain exist? Is there any source that explains the model and/or the calculations ?